# Issue with response.xpath().extract_first() method

Tags: python, json, regex, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm having some trouble extracting images URL's from amazon's site.

I managed to get the script that contains all the URL's but, when extracting comes into play, things don't work that well.

For example, lets take this amazon product:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0711BMXVB?pf_rd_p=1581d9f4-062f-453c-b69e-0f3e00ba2652&pf_rd_r=YY1VTQE69K265SDTNETW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0711BMXVB)

With the xpath

```
//script[contains(., "ImageBlockATF")]/text()
```

You can get the part of the source code that contains URL's. I've been getting this script by doing

```
s = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "ImageBlockATF")]/text()').extract_first()
```

And then, for getting the individual URL's, something like this

```
m = re.search(r'^var data = ({.*};)', s, re.S | re.M)
data = m.groups()[0]
```

The issue I'm having is that, for `re.search` to work, I need `s` to be a string and this is not happening. When the code reaches `data = m.groups()[0]` an error occurs, where `m`, because `s` was "not" a string, cant apply the `.groups` method.

I can't figure out what's going on because `s` is in fact a string, `/text()` returns a string, I have checked the type and it comes out as `str` (also tried doing `str(s)` but didn't work either).

Also, if I force a string into `s`, something like:

```
s = "P.when('A').register("ImageBlockATF", function(A){
    var data = {
                'colorImages': { 'initial': [{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Qs-sOznzL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rNitnJpsL._US40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rNitnJpsL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Qs-sOznzL._UX395_.jpg":[282,395],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Qs-sOznzL._UX500_.jpg":[357,500],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Qs-sOznzL._UX535_.jpg":[382,535],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Qs-sOznzL._UX575_.jpg":[410,575],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Qs-sOznzL._UX625_.jpg":[446,625],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Qs-sOznzL._UX675_.jpg":[481,675],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81Qs-sOznzL._UX695_.jpg":[496,695]},"variant":"MAIN","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ZLo7ef-GL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Q1eJ1c1tL._US40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Q1eJ1c1tL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ZLo7ef-GL._UY395_.jpg":[395,249],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ZLo7ef-GL._UY500_.jpg":[500,316],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ZLo7ef-GL._UY535_.jpg":[535,338],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ZLo7ef-GL._UY575_.jpg":[575,363],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ZLo7ef-GL._UY625_.jpg":[625,395],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ZLo7ef-GL._UY675_.jpg":[675,426],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ZLo7ef-GL._UY695_.jpg":[695,439]},"variant":"FRNT","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Fny8%2BI-mL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BKgvmEndL._US40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51%2BKgvmEndL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Fny8%2BI-mL._UY395_.jpg":[395,301],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Fny8%2BI-mL._UY500_.jpg":[500,381],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Fny8%2BI-mL._UY535_.jpg":[535,408],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Fny8%2BI-mL._UY575_.jpg":[575,438],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Fny8%2BI-mL._UY625_.jpg":[625,477],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Fny8%2BI-mL._UY675_.jpg":[675,515],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Fny8%2BI-mL._UY695_.jpg":[695,530]},"variant":"BACK","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71a7BKbdD3L._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31rBxkzNDgL._US40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31rBxkzNDgL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71a7BKbdD3L._UX395_.jpg":[146,395],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71a7BKbdD3L._UX500_.jpg":[185,500],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71a7BKbdD3L._UX535_.jpg":[198,535],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71a7BKbdD3L._UX575_.jpg":[213,575],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71a7BKbdD3L._UX625_.jpg":[231,625],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71a7BKbdD3L._UX675_.jpg":[250,675],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71a7BKbdD3L._UX695_.jpg":[257,695]},"variant":"BOTT","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/8139cgDppVL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qECXntKAL._US40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41qECXntKAL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/8139cgDppVL._UX395_.jpg":[139,395],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/8139cgDppVL._UX500_.jpg":[177,500],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/8139cgDppVL._UX535_.jpg":[189,535],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/8139cgDppVL._UX575_.jpg":[203,575],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/8139cgDppVL._UX625_.jpg":[221,625],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/8139cgDppVL._UX675_.jpg":[238,675],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/8139cgDppVL._UX695_.jpg":[245,695]},"variant":"TOPP","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81a3uUSxI%2BL._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rT%2B2GI9ZL._US40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rT%2B2GI9ZL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81a3uUSxI%2BL._UX395_.jpg":[186,395],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81a3uUSxI%2BL._UX500_.jpg":[235,500],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81a3uUSxI%2BL._UX535_.jpg":[252,535],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81a3uUSxI%2BL._UX575_.jpg":[271,575],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81a3uUSxI%2BL._UX625_.jpg":[294,625],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81a3uUSxI%2BL._UX675_.jpg":[318,675],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81a3uUSxI%2BL._UX695_.jpg":[327,695]},"variant":"RGHT","lowRes":null},{"hiRes":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815uXTfk02L._UL1500_.jpg","thumb":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/419Wv4M%2B-bL._US40_.jpg","large":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/419Wv4M%2B-bL.jpg","main":{"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815uXTfk02L._UX395_.jpg":[255,395],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815uXTfk02L._UX500_.jpg":[322,500],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815uXTfk02L._UX535_.jpg":[345,535],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815uXTfk02L._UX575_.jpg":[371,575],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815uXTfk02L._UX625_.jpg":[403,625],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815uXTfk02L._UX675_.jpg":[435,675],"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815uXTfk02L._UX695_.jpg":[448,695]},"variant":"PAIR","lowRes":null}]},
                'colorToAsin': {'initial': {}},
                'holderRatio': 1.2,
                'holderMaxHeight': 700,
                'heroImage': {'initial': []},
                'heroVideo': {'initial': []},
                'spin360ColorData': {'initial': {}},
                'spin360ColorEnabled': {'initial': 0},
                'spin360ConfigEnabled': false,
                'spin360LazyLoadEnabled': false,
                'playVideoInImmersiveView':'false',
                'tabbedImmersiveViewTreatment':'C',
                'totalVideoCount':'0',
                'videoIngressATFSlateThumbURL':'',
                'mediaTypeCount':'0',
                'atfEnhancedHoverOverlay' : true,
                'winningAsin': 'B072596K2C',
                'weblabs' : {},
                'aibExp3Layout' : 1,
                'aibRuleName' : 'frank-powered',
                'acEnabled' : false
                };
    A.trigger('P.AboveTheFold'); // trigger ATF event.
    return data;
    });"
```

It works just fine.

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 30, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Users\Manuel\Desktop\scrapyProject\genericScraper\genericScraper\spiders\finalClothes_spider.py", line 59, in parse
    data = m.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Most probably there was no match. Always check if there is a match first, before accessing `groups()`. `m.groups()[0]` is rather a convoluted way of expressing `m.group()`

Comment: Tried out using `group()` instead of `groups()[0]` but i'm still getting the same error

Comment: Did you check for a match? `if m:` then get `m.group()`.

Comment: Seems there is no match, code never enters the `if` statement. I don't get why it works if i hardcode the string instead of getting it from `response.xpath`

Comment: Then your xpath is not finding any element. Check what document you are querying.

Comment: Xpath is indeed finding elements, if i do `print(s)` it shows a string almost the same (different urls) as the one hardcoded.

Comment: Does it return byte strings? Try `rb'^var data = ({.*};)'`

Comment: It doesn't seem like it, using what you suggested I get, when it reaches `m = re.search`, `TypeError = cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object`

Comment: Please, rewrite your question to focus on the actual problem (regular expression that unexpectedly does not match) and include code to reproduce the issue (the input string that works and the input string that does not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using another approach.

```
imagenesString = str(response.xpath('//*[contains(@type, "text/javascript") and contains(.,"ImageBlockATF") and not(contains(.,"jQuery"))]').extract())

imagenes = re.findall('\"large\":\"(https.*?\.jpg)\"', imagenesString)
```

Now `imagenes` is a list with all the URL's